# How to send custom status code?

Tags: python, tornado

I have tornado handler:

```
class DumbHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, dumb):
        self.clear()
        self.set_status(555)
        self.write(
            json.dumps({
                'error_code': 211
            })
        )
```

but I have exception:

```
ValueError: ('unknown status code %d', 555)
```

I want to send my own status code (555), how to do it?

Comment: [`RequestHandler.set_status(status_code, reason=None)`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=status%20code#tornado.web.RequestHandler.set_status)

Answer (score 2):

according to the documentation for [`RequestHandler.set_status(status_code, reason=None)`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=status%20code#tornado.web.RequestHandler.set_status):

> - status_code (int) – Response status code. **If reason is None, it must be present in httplib.responses.**

you need to provide a reason for custom status codes.

You can put an empty string for a reason:

```
self.set_status(555, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

555 is not valid status code, you must use the status code listed here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html#http-status-codes

Or, you can add reason when use set_status(555, "my custom status code").